# How to debug lightning-cli invoice

Tags: core-lightning

I tried:

```
lightning-cli invoice 100 invoice20190126 payme
```

and nothing happens. How to debug?

Answer (score 2):

I have copy and pasted the command to my c-lighting node and it works producing the following output:

```
lightning-cli invoice 100 invoice20190126 payme
{
  "payment_hash": "af2a2e0a6f4924f755e296c219ade5f2c65616fcec5bb8e62b253b8a71a442cb", 
  "expires_at": 1548528927, 
  "bolt11": "lnbc1n1pwye8cdpp54u4zuzn0fyj0w40zjmppnt097tr9v9hua3dm3e3ty5ac5udygt9sdqgwpshjmt9cqp2rzjqgj8m8dsm7h75az7lry7zc0txghh8tpl3pvdsuctdlvhy4r50nnkkzrgpvqqf0cqqqqqqq05qqqqraqqjq9c06msw62wushzceav74p2zzmznmtud4c3hkw6keqvquxnm6kaxry4rm7aerwppl4jn5xm7tyjxvvyyve5w06slwm7fvxfspx363j9cqcevtr7"
}
```

Which version of c-lightning are you using? 
Also there was recently a change of the JSON RPC API due to the new plugin system. Could it be that you have not updated `lightning-cli` but only `lightningd`?

Answer (score 0):

I use docker-compose and don't see the version there. I have stopped, removed the container and rebuild clightning_bitcoin. Now it is working! Thanks! The respond is:

```
lightning-cli invoice 100 invoice20190126 payme
{
  "payment_hash": "374c59643514b917da44ba737f6dcdf59cf6708903e6403f9477022185c91c18", 
  "expires_at": 1548530289, 
  "bolt11": "lnbc1n1pwyefrppp5xax9jep4zju30kjyhfeh7mwd7kw0vuyfq0nyq0u5wupzrpwfrsvqdqgwpshjmt9cqp2rzjqwac3nxyg3f5mfa4ke9577c4u8kvkx8pqtdsusqdfww0aymk823x6zyyhgqqv0gqqyqqqqqqqqqqqqgqjqt96ykzgwc5qd9034mfw4khlypu4zx9qwdzjvsg4dpfrffdg9qvgnk2uey6h7f4g9663rvqaucnfn95j2taruezgdh3w6w3v2xauzvjqp47g2m5"
}
```

Comment: you can see the version with lightning-cli getinfo

Comment: I get for version: "version": "",